# Get the content from a textarea? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Im really new to jQuery, i want to get the text from a textarea into a mysql database. But i first wanted to try how i can get the text from it. So i made a little script:

```
<textarea id="textfeld" class="form" rows="4"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button">Submit</button>
```

and:

```
     $('input#button').click(function() {
    var inhalt = $('#textfeld').val();
    alert(inhalt);
});
```

Im doing this site with the bootstrap framwork so jQuery is "plugged in" (sorry bad english) , but if i press my button after i put some text in my textarea nothing appears

Thx for help! (Maybe you cane give me a little tip for the future how i get this into my mysql database :) )

Comment: The element with the `id` of `#button` isn't an `input`, it is a `button`.. working example - http://jsfiddle.net/y1eo2ba6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is somewhat off. Whenever using an ID selector there is no need to use any other selector since IDs should be unique:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var inhalt = $('#textfeld').val();
    alert(inhalt);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textfeld" class="form" rows="4"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="button">Submit</button>
```